# Java Thread Bind Exception combined with address already in use error (client server using sockets)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

There are two files (client file, server file) in this program that are supposed to be able to send and receive messages (utf-8 strings) to each other. Each file has a thread (one thread for client, one thread for server)

The client and the server connect on localhost with a port number (it should be the same port number when typing on the command prompt / mac terminal window)

However, the server is supposed to only send messages to all the other clients after receiving a message from a client. In other words, if a client sends a message to the server, the server cannot send that message back to the same client--it can only send messages to the different clients.

Another way to say it: Once a client is connected, it can send messages to the server. It will also receive from the server all messages sent from the other connected clients (not the messages sent from itself).

At runtime, there is supposed to be only one server (mac terminal / command prompt windows) but there can be multiple/infinite number of clients (mac terminal / command prompt windows)

Screenshot of error (server side):

[image]

Screenshot of error (client side):

[image]

Code of ChatServer.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatServer
{
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread ChatServer1 = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    int port_number1 = 0;
                    int numberOfClients = 0;
                    boolean KeepRunning = true;
                    if(args.length>0)
                    {
                        port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Waiting for connections on port " + port_number1);

                    try 
                    {
                        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Listening for connections on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );
                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {
                        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                        //create a list of clients
                        ArrayList<String> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<String>();

                        //connect to client
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();  

                        //add new client to the list, is this the right way to add a new client? or should it be in a for loop or something?
                        ListOfClients.add("new client");
                        numberOfClients += 1;

                        System.out.println("A client has connected. Waiting for message...");
                        ListOfClients.add("new client" + numberOfClients);

                        //reading encoded utf-8 message from client, decoding from utf-8 format 
                        String MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8 = "";
                        BufferedReader BufReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedFromUTF8 = BufReader1.readLine();
                        byte[] bytes = MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedUTF8 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");


                        //relaying message to every other client besides the one it was from

                        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if(ListOfClients.get(i)!="new client")
                            {
                                   String newmessage = null;
                                   String returnMessage = newmessage;
                                   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                   bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
                                   System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+returnMessage);
                                   bw.flush();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (socket != null)
                        {
                            socket.close ();
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        ChatServer1.start();
    }
}
```

Code of ChatClient.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatClient
{
    private static Socket Socket;
    static int numberOfClients = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
              //If I wanted to create multiple clients, would this code go here? OR should the new thread creation be outside the while(true) loop?
              while (true)
              {
                  String host = "localhost";
                  int numberOfClients = 0;
                  Thread ChatClient1 = new Thread ()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {   
                          try
                          {
                              //Client begins, gets port number, listens, connects, prints out messages from other clients
                              int port = 0;
                              int port_1number1 = 0;
                              int numberofmessages = 0;
                              String[] messagessentbyotherclients = null;
                              System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                              System.out.println("Chat client is running");
                              String port_number1= args[0];
                              System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                              if(args.length>0)
                              {
                                  port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                              }
                              System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                              System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + port_number1 );
                              Socket.connect(null);
                              System.out.println("Client has connected to the server");
                              for(int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
                              {
                                  System.out.println(messagessentbyotherclients);
                              }

                              //client creates new message from standard input
                              OutputStream os = Socket.getOutputStream();
                              OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                              BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                              //creating message to send from standard input
                              String newmessage = "";
                              try   
                              {
                                  // input the message from standard input encoded in UTF-8 string format
                                  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                  String line = "";
                                  System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );
                                  while( (line= input.readLine()) != null )     
                                  {
                                      newmessage += line + " ";
                                      input=null;
                                  }
                              }
                              catch ( Exception e )
                              {
                                  System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                              }
                              //Sending the message to server
                              String sendMessage = newmessage;
                              bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                              bw.flush();
                              System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                          } 
                          catch (IOException e)
                          {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      }
                  };
                  ChatClient1.start();
        }
    }
}
```

These two errors have been covered many times and I've heard that the answer is to put the socket in a loop, which it already is in (while loop).

My question is: Is there a way to locate the errors before running it? Whenever I compile the program I don't get any errors in eclipse, but when I run it in the command prompt window / mac terminal, it does tell me that something is wrong. Or perhaps there's a line of code that I'm overlooking?

Comment: i took a shallow look over your code and i saw several problems. In your server you call `new ServerSocket(port_number1);` more than once, and every time you repeat that call you get the bind exception; you should create the server socket only once. In server, you should create one thread for each connected client, or use a NIO selector, or else your only server thread won't be able to attend the clients

Comment: it'll be much easier if you run one client instance per program instance instead of all the clients in the same program. In the latter case you would need one thread for each client, which would make the client code much more complex. I strongly suggest you to rethink all of your client and server code architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
```

Place it once, before the `while` loop.